# Random uniform distribution of predicted numbers using Keras Custom Loss function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I am implementing a custom loss function where the expectation is to predict the labels evenly/uniformly.
i.e., Given a set of labels say - [1,2,3,4,5], we need to maximize the entropy of the output number. Every single outcome should have equal probability.

I am not sure how to achieve the equal probability here, is just adding equal weights enough?

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, kernel_initializer='uniform', input_shape=(5,)))
model.add(layers.Activation('softmax'))

def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
   squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
   return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)

weights = {1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1, 5:1}
model.fit(x_train, y_train,verbose=1, epochs=10,class_weight=weights)
```

Comment: I would try to negate loss function to get maximum entropy (instead of minimum): add minus here: return -tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)